# angular- How fields inside class gets mapped to tags in html template

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am going through video tutorials and came across this code in angular-

```
import{Component} from '@angular/core';
component({
selector: 'course',
template: `
<input [value]="email" (keyup.enter)="onKeyUp()"/>`
})

export class CourseComponent{

email="me@example.com";

onKeyUp(){

console.log(this.email)
}
}
```

Now email at input element(in template) is different from one declared inside a class.When we do console.log(this.email), it is taking value of input field email(when we enter email at frontend input box). I need to understand how the email from  input element is getting displayed when I have done console.log(this.email)(shouldn't it display the email given inside the class?). How this mapping is happening between input element email and the one declared inside class.I think its something related to class concepts but I cant get it. Detailed explanation will be helpful. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thats the two way data binding concept in Angular. It will update DOM to Model  and Model to DOM. https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html

Answer (score 0):

That is what we call [Two-way Data Binding](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/10/13/two-way-data-binding-in-angular-2.html).

The line that you specify `email="me@example.com";` is where you initialize the data into email variable, and this variable is bound in the `<input [value]="email" (keyup.enter)="onKeyUp()"/>` so whenever the data inside the email variable is changed, it will affect in the component script too.

Answer (score 0):

This will print only initial value "me@example.com" that you have assigned while component creation. It will not print your updated value from "input" tag as it is only one way binding. You can check it in console as well by updating "email" value. That is called: Element property binding or One-way binding from data source to view target.

To see changes vice versa from "view to component" and "component to view" you need to add two-way binding "[()]".